# Move all windows to next monitor (1-2, 2-3, 3-1)

Tags: windows, window

Is there a way to move all windows to next monitor?

ie.
windows on the first monitor goes to the second.
windows on the second monitor goes to the third.
windows on the third monitor goes to the first.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I'm curious, What's the main purpose of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that from

Windows 7:  Right click on desktop -> Screen resolution.

Windows 10:  Right click on Start Menu -> Control Panel -> Display -> Screen resolution

Click identify, so you know what monitors your system numbered each monitor.  Rearrange the monitors by dragging them to the position you have on your desk.  If you monitors are not all the same and perfectly aligned on your desk, you can put a window so that half of it is on one screen and the other half is on another.  Then use the arrow keys to move the monitor up or down to get it to align.

Comment: Hi Kevin. This doesn't seem to be what the OP is looking for. You seem to be describing the process of telling Windows what the physical layout of the monitors is, so that for example dragging corresponds to how the monitors are physically placed on the desk, whereas it appears to me the OP wants a way to (perhaps through a shortcut) shuffle all open windows around, without rearranging the monitors themselves either physically or logically. It's great that you are trying to help people out, but please take care to ensure that you are actually *answering the question as asked*.

Comment: Oh, I see now.  I don't know of anything to make all windows move, but I know this program can do one window at a time.:  http://www.mediachance.com/free/multimon.htm.  I used to use it years ago.